# Why my variable is not iterable when i loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iterator

I try to loop the 2d arrays, but the I variable is undefined or not iterable, why?
can anyone tell me ??

```js
function sum (arr) {
  var total = 0
  for(let [a1,a2,a3] of arr){
    for(let i of [a1,a2,a3]){
      for(let j of i){
        total += j
      }
    }
    if(typeof a2 == "undefined" && typeof a3 == "undefined"){
      a2 = [0]
      a3 = [0]
    }
  }     
};


console.log(sum([
  [
    [10, 10],
    [15],
    [1, 1]
  ],
  [
    [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    [4],
    [9, 11]
  ],
  [
    [3, 5, 1],
    [1, 5, 3],
    [1]
  ],
  [
    [90]
  ]
]));
```

but when i sum another 2D array, it works, like this :

```js
function sum (arr) {
  var total = 0
  for(let [a1,a2,a3] of arr){
    for(let i of [a1,a2,a3]){
      for(let j of i){
        total += j
      }
    }
  }
  return total
}  


console.log(sum([
  [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [9, 1, 2, 10],
    [9, 4, 3]
  ],
  [
    [4, 14, 31],
    [9, 10, 18, 12, 20],
    [1, 4, 90]
  ],
  [
    [2, 5, 10],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 5, 10]
  ]
]));
```

i try to loop 3 times for this 2d arrays, the first top code is each lengths are diffreen in array
and the last code is same,

Comment: Why destructure and build up the array again?

Comment: i watched that way on stackoverflow also from an answrr, @JonasWilms

Comment: Is destructuring better than just looping through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause

```
 let [a1,a2,a3] of [ [90] ])
```

will result in `a2` and `a3` being undefined, therefore in the following line it is:

```
 for(const i of [90, undefined, undefined])
```

And at the second index it does:

```
 for(let j of undefined)
```

which doesnt work.

Comment: you were said `Why to destructure and build up the array again?` 
is that way not recommended to use ?? @jonasWilms

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move your if statement that checks if the value is undefined and assigns it to zero if it is ahead of the part of code that iterates over those values. You were getting this error because there wasn't anything there.

```
function sumTwo(arr) {
    var total = 0
    for(let [a1,a2,a3] of arr){
    if(typeof a2 == "undefined" && typeof a3 == "undefined"){
        a2 = [0]
        a3 = [0]
      }
      for(let i of [a1,a2,a3]){
        for(let j of i){
          total += j
        }
      }
    }     
    return total
  };


  console.log(sumTwo([
    [
      [10, 10],
      [15],
      [1, 1]
    ],
    [
      [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
      [4],
      [9, 11]
    ],
    [
      [3, 5, 1],
      [1, 5, 3],
      [1]
    ],
    [
      [90]
    ]
  ])); //prints 237
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
let [a1,a2,a3] of [ [90] ])
```

there is no a2 or a3 there...

My suggestion would be using the code before you get into the first for loop:

```
if(arr.length < 3){
   for(let y = arr.length, y > 3, y++ ){
     arr.push(0)
   }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to recursively reduce the array using concat until you have a flat array and then reduce that to the sum of it's numbers:

```js
const arr = [
  [[10, 10], [15], [1, 1]],
  [[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [4], [9, 11]],
  [[3, 5, 1], [1, 5, 3], [1]],
  [[90]],
];

const flatten = (arr) => {
  const recur = (result, item) =>
    !Array.isArray(item)
      ? result.concat(item)
      : result.concat(item.reduce(recur, []));
  return arr.reduce(recur, []);
};

console.log(
  flatten(arr).reduce((result, item) => result + item, 0),
);
```

Comment: can u recode it by es5 ? i dont understand it at all, because i still learning

Comment: please explaining it ? @HMR

Comment: @ZrClassic It's using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) [recursively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to flatten a multi dimentional array. Then using reduce again to get the sum. In the future I'd advice you to google something you don't undersand.

Comment: @ZrClassic If you're just starting to learn Ecmascript then it may be better to start with [ES6](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20%26%20beyond)